# How to estimate differences between two normal means when variances are tested to be unequal

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, estimation, inference, estimators

Let $X_1 X_2...X_n, Y_1 Y_2...Y_n$ be $\sim N(\mu_x$, $\sigma_x^2$), $\sim N(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2$).

I want to estimate ($\mu_x - \mu_y$) and have used F-test to see that $\sigma_x^2$ $\neq$ $\sigma_y^2$ at 90% confidence interval.

Not able to use $\frac{(\bar{X}-\bar{Y})-(\mu_x - \mu_y)}{\sqrt{\frac{{S_x^2}}{n_x}+\frac{S_y^2}{n_y}}} \sim t_{n-1}$, I wonder how can I do such estimation? As easy as possible please.

For example, if we are to estimate the return outperformance between $stock_{walmart}$ and $stock_{netflex}$ over some n periods, "knowing" their variances are unequal. Assuming returns are normal and forget about non-stationarity and other realistic aspects. How should we do it?

Comment: You have to perform the welch test to test for differences in the means. However, the degrees of freedom of the associated t-distribution must be modified (Satterthwaite's correction).

Comment: I looked up welch t test, and it seems like the appropriate one for this exercise. While you are here, what's the nonparametric equivalent for testing means? Mann Whitney tests for same distribution and same mean right, but I would like to test the above stock example with returns different and non-normal.

Comment: I'd advise against testing equality of variance to choose what test to use. If you can't reasonably assume equal variance (at least under the null), then simply don't assume it. (However, if the sample sizes are equal the usual test is pretty robust to unequal variances, so it's not much of an issue in that situation).

Comment: So if I can't reasonably assume variance equality, what test should I look at